# Returning HTML and JSON to jquery post call in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application I need to return a html view to Jquery post() call that will be made by java script 
As of now I was returning JSON only and it was done in the following way

```
render json: results
```

How do I return both JSON data and HTML data to be processed in JQuery?
and Where do I store this view file?

Comment: Just for the sake of fun, try `rails g scaffold article title desc`, then `rake db:migrate` then `rails s` then in browser `localhost:3000/articles/new` create new data then try `localhost:3000/articles/1` also `localhost:3000/articles/1.json` also do mind the codes in `app/controllers/articles_controller.rb` and `app/views/articles/show.html.erb`.

Comment: Can you explain that what exactly your fun task is trying to do?/

Comment: See how your problem gets answered, you can see in the controller file how rails handles both json and html format, and also you can see how html files are rendered. Do give it a try... you could remove these files when you are done, no big deal `rails d scaffold article`.. and its all gone....

Answer (score 0):

You can use respond_to in the controller. And then depending on the format sent by the jQuery request, either will be executed (foo.json or just foo, though you can force the content type in jQuery too so check this).

```
respond_to do |which|
  which.html # Renders the view
  which.json { render json: results }
end
```